# Валидация pydantic. Проверить что строка не содержит определённых символов

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, pydantic

Мне надо убедиться что строка не содержит символов кириллицы. Делаю проверку подобным образом:

```
class MyModel(BaseModel):
    content_en: str = Field(pattern=r"[^а-яА-Я]")
```

Но при передаче в поле `content_en` строки содержащие кириллицу не вызывается ошибка.
Как правильно сделать проверку?
Python 3.8
Pydantic 2.5

Comment: у меня ваша валидация срабатывает правильно. есть подозрение, что кодировка шаблона валидации не совпадает с кодировкой вводимой строки.

Comment: @strawdog я не знаток, конечно, как оно там в питоне, но данное выражение проверит, что во входной строке есть хотя бы один символ не кириллицы. Оно не исключает что ее там в принципе нет. чтобы ее там не было полностью надо взять что-то вроде `/^[^а-яё]+$/iu`

Answer (score 2):

Вам, вероятно, нужно использовать выражение вида

```
r"^[^а-яё]+$"i
```

https://regex101.com/r/UK7yT2/1
то есть обозначить начало и конец строки, и определить, что все символы внутри - не кириллица. Флаг `i` - регистронезависимость.
Отдельно следует заметить, что буква `ё` не входит в диапазон `а-я`.

В приведенном же вами коде выражение проверяет, что в искомой строке есть хотя бы один символ отличный от кириллицы.

Answer (score 1):

Решил вопрос вот так:

```
class MyModel(BaseModel):
    content_en: str = Field(pattern=r"^[^а-яА-ЯёЁ]*$")
```

`r"^[^а-яА-ЯёЁ]+$"` тоже работает.